# Will updating software with a 'deb' file remove the previous version?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, deb

Unity (the programming environment, not the GUI) has [a Linux version that is installed with a `deb` file](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/).

- Currently, I'm running this beta version: `unity-editor-5.5.0b2+20160906_amd64.deb`
- It keeps crashing on me, so I want to revert to a previous, more stable version: `unity-editor-5.4.1f1+20160913_amd64.deb`

Can I just install the `5.4.1` deb file, or will I run into problems because  a newer version already exists on my system? Or, will I end up with two versions existing simultaneously on my system?

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Installing an application from `.deb` file using `dpkg -i` will replace the currently installed version with the one specified in the command. Even if the installed one is newer.

This is if the software can be installed with a single deb file (like the atom text editor).

But if it requires more packages to be pulled to be installed, then you may need to do `sudo apt-get -f install` after `dpkg -i` command. However, in this case, if you already have newer versions of those other packages, you may need to force package managers to downgrade these versions. Otherwise, `apt-get -f install` will end up installing the newer one.